# Print only the value of a field in Form

Tags: cakephp

I would echo the value of the fields of a `Model` in cakePhp, without creating a Form.
Is it possible with core Helper or I have to build a custom one?
In particulare, if I use

```
echo $this->Form->input('field',array('label'=>"This is my value:"))
```

it prints out an input with a `label`.

What I want is something like:

```
echo $this->Form->label('field',array('label'=>"This is my value:"))
```

and it shall print out

`"This is my value: <value_of_field>"`

Answer (score 2):

All the values that the `FormHelper` uses are from `$this->request->data`, so, try printing `echo $this->request->data[YourModel][field];`

If not, then you can define a view variable in the controller via `$this->set('variableName', variableValue);` and assign it in the form field.

Comment: @giuseppe when we use something like `$this->Form->input('field',array('label'=>"This is my value:"))` it generate `<label>your message</label>` its up to you how you make accessible this label message to controller

Comment: In fact, when you use `$this->Form->input('field');`, it will generate `<label for="xxxx">Field</label>`. So if you want to edit all labels, you have to do as @RajeevRanjan says.